# How to enable tracing logs in Apache Camel 3.x?

Tags: logging, apache-camel, trace-logging

I'm trying to migrate from Camel 2.X to 3.X and have a question regarding camel logging.

I'm able to set route tracing by enabling **.tracing()** on camel context. To debug some issues just route tracing is not enough and it is necessary to be able to view camel logs in trace.

I have enabled the trace level in our custom log4j configuration as below.

*name="org.apache.camel" level="TRACE"*

But I'm unable to get the trace logs from Camel.

For ex. Logs like:

*if (LOG.isTraceEnabled()) {
LOG.trace("Waiting for asynchronous callback before continuing for exchangeId: {} -> {}", exchange.getExchangeId(), exchange);
}*

from *DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager*.

Does anyone how to enable Camel trace logs or where to find some information on same?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I see TRACE logs when using the following log4j2 configuration:

```
appender.out.type = Console
appender.out.name = out
appender.out.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.out.layout.pattern = %d [%15.15t] %highlight{%-5p} %-30.30c - %m%n
rootLogger.level = INFO
rootLogger.appenderRef.out.ref = out

loggers = mine,camel
logger.mine.name = org.example
logger.mine.level = INFO
logger.camel.name = org.apache.camel
logger.camel.level = TRACE
```

Comment: I have set org.apache.camel to TRACE level. However, I can see the trace logs only from  org.apache.camel.component.jms.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer class and not from any other camel classes. Any idea why so? Am I missing something?